# Access Modem interface through WAN ports

Tags: router, pppoe

**I have multi WAN load balancer "Peplink Balance 310" router:**

- Subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
- Router IP: 192.168.0.1
- LAN Configuration: http://screencast.com/t/RnXy2hBxurnN

**It connects to two DSL modems/routers through WAN1/2:**

- *WAN1: Huawei HG532n Router:*

  - Bridged mode enabled @ LAN1
  - Subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
  - Router/Modem IP: 192.168.1.1
  - Peplink WAN1 Port configuration: http://screencast.com/t/S9huQrkr7Q
- *WAN2: Asus N55U Router:*

  - Bridged mode enabled @ LAN4
  - Subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
  - Router/Modem IP: 192.168.2.1
  - Peplink WAN2 Port configuration: http://screencast.com/t/JPv6JdrJ

My Question is: Is how to access these routers interface through the peplink balance 310? so i want to access the interfaces 192.168.1/2.1
Right now my only option is to turn on the wifi interface on both routers each time then connect to them, and access their interfaces to check on dsl status etc..

Comment: Are you using drop-in mode on the peplink? Can you not connect to either of them right now? You may need to add static routes on each PPPoE device to the 192.168.0.0/24 network so it knows to route that traffic back inside to the LAN.

Comment: Thanks @Rex my answers: 1. I'm not using the drop-in mode (called IP Forwarding) at the above screenshots. 2. I can't connect to either of them at the moment. 3. How do i add the static routes? i mean what i'm going to fill in and i have to do that at each Modem/router right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create outbound polices to access the GUI's of devices on the WAN.
To access your Huawei, create an outbound policy with the following criteria;
Name "Huawei" (can be any name)
Source "Any" (where the traffic is coming from)
Destination "192.168.1.1" (the IP address if the Huawei GUI)
Protocol "Any" (selects which protocols the apply the rule to)
Algorithm "Enforced" (Forces all traffic matching the above criteria to only use the WAN specified below)
Enforced Connection "WAN 1" (The WAN your Huawei router is connected to)
Save the rules and Apply.

[image]